# Working with a foreign language codebase

Tags: visual-studio, webforms

I work with French-Canadians on a medium to large Web form app.  French is their native language while mine is English.  I just wondered what others have done in similar situations.  I've search for a Translator Extension that would work in Visual Studio but haven't come up with anything.

Usually I just copy and paste portions into Bing/Google Translate but that makes it pretty tedious.

Comment: Tell them to write code and comments in English.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about project management and not programming.

Comment: I'll close this to avoid the backlash but it's not really about project management.  I have no say over any of this and, thru a merger, am the only native English dev.  The code base is quite large and I just need to find a way to deal with the existing.  Going forward they are making an effort to use English.

Comment: I am French, and I know it's not an easy language to master, use the google translator to switch from french to english works well, however the reverse gives results often surprising!

I think the best way is to learn french (even if it's hard) rather than using software translations (google translation or reverso are the most used here)

Comment: I believe international teams should work in English as it's a common denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a nice Visual Studio extension for translating source code on fly:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f2321406-c5bb-42b7-9660-dfacd313eeed

It's not as perfect as it could be (which I imagine could be on fly translation of the whole class/file), but it's far more better than switching between windows and copy-pasting to google translator. By the way - the tool uses Google translate and does it quite effectively.